# How to make python re treat continuous matching pattern options to be a single occurrence of the pattern?

Tags: python, regex

I am developing a chatbot, in which I would like to embed certain rules. One of those would be to parse questions like this:

"How much is twelve thousand three hundred four plus two hundred fifty six?"
OR
"What is five hundred eighty nine divided by 89?"

I have the following code:

```
import re

pat_num = re.compile(r'((\b(zero|one|two|three|four|five|'
                     r'six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|'
                     r'twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|sixteen|'
                     r'seventeen|eighteen|nineteen|twenty|thirty|'
                     r'forty|fifty|sixty|seventy|eighty|'
                     r'ninety|hundred|thousand|million|billion|'
                     r'trillion)\b)+|\d+)')
ind_list = [(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(pat_num, sentence)]
```

I want both sentences to return two numbers. For example, for the first sentence, it should return the indexes for number: twelve thousand three hundred four, and two hundred fifty six.

However, it returns 9 numbers/matches for the first one, which are: twelve, thousand, three, hundred, four, two, hundred, fifty, six.

How to change the regular expression to make it return 2 numbers?

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the numeral pattern using a block, `<numeral>(?:[\s-]<numeral>)*`, that will match a numeral  and then any 0+ sequences of a whitespace or `-` followed with a numeral.

```
import re
numeral_rx = r'(?:zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|sixteen|seventeen|eighteen|nineteen|twenty|thirty|forty|fifty|sixty|seventy|eighty|ninety|hundred|thousand|million|billion|trillion)'
sentences=["How much is twelve thousand three hundred four plus two hundred fifty six?",
"How much is twelve thousand three hundred and four divided by two hundred fifty-six?"]
pat_num = re.compile(r'\b{0}(?:(?:\s+(?:and\s+)?|-){0})*\b|\d+'.format(numeral_rx))
for sentence in sentences:
    print(re.findall(pat_num, sentence))
# => ['twelve thousand three hundred four', 'two hundred fifty six']
#    ['twelve thousand three hundred and four', 'two hundred fifty-six']
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/Q446DV).

Note that due to the non-capturing groups `(?:...)` a simple `re.findall` call is enough to obtain all matches.

**Details**:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `{0}` - the alternation group with numeral strings placeholder
- `(?:(?:\s+(?:and\s+)?|-){0})*` - 0 or more sequences of:

  - `(?:\s+(?:and\s+)?|-)` - either of the two alternatives:

    - `\s+(?:and\s+)?` - 1+ whitespaces followed with 1 or 0 occurrences (an optional one) of `and` substring and 1+ whitespaces
    - `|` - or
    - `-` - a hyphen
  - `{0}` -  the alternation group with numeral strings placeholder
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `|` - or
- `\d+`  - 1+ digits.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much, Wiktor.

Comment: I guess the reason mine did not work was because when the previous word was matched, a space/word boundary (\b) was eaten, therefore the next one was not preceded with one space any more, and hence was not matched. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: @BoShao: The `\b` word boundary is a *zero-width assertion* that does not *consume* text. It matches a *location* (=empty string) at [certain places](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/1539/word-boundary). Since it cannot match a whitespace, your initial regex fails to match substrings containing spaces. `\b\w+\b` matches a whole word, but `(?:\b\w+\b)+` will never match 2 or more words (in EMEA-like languages where space is used to separate words) because it does not match space. You need a `-`, too, as there might be `twenty-two`.

Comment: I need the dash and even the word "and". For the word "and", I want to make sure the pattern does not match it as the start nor the end. Is there a way to do that? Thank you very much. Below are 3 sentences to test:"What is two hundred and four plus one and something?",
        "What is two hundred and four plus one and and something?",
        "What is two hundred and four plus and and and something?",

Comment: Actually, a real problem is that this pattern does not match the number words if there are multiple spaces in between. For examples: "twelve thousand     three hundred and four" will be considered as two numbers. How can I address this problem? If this is resolved, I can easily deal with the "and" problem as well (I can just replace "and" with 3 spaces before checking the pattern).

Comment: @BoShao: Use this then: `r'\b{0}(?:(?:\s+(?:and\s+)?|-){0})*\b|\d+'`

Comment: Thank you very much. It works for multiple spaces now, but do not match dash any more. For example, this fails to match: "How much is twelve thousand     three hundred and four divided by two hundred fifty-six?"

Comment: You are right, Wiktor, it works now. It was my bad because I forgot to update the code for converting the number words to numbers, and therefore thought it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you want to have the actual indexes instead of the matched text itself, it should be quite trivial with a little bit of lookahead:

```
# easier to manage as a list
numerals = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine",
            "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen",
            "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen", "twenty", "thirty", "fourty", "fifty",
            "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety", "hundred", "thousand", "million",
            "billion", "trillion"]

pattern = re.compile(r"((({})\s*)+)(?=\s|$)|\d+".format("|".join(numerals)))  # all together
```

You can then test it as:

```
sentence = "How much is twelve thousand three hundred four plus two hundred fifty six?"
print([(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(pattern, sentence)])
# [(12, 46), (52, 69)]

sentence = "What is five hundred eighty nine divided by 89?"
print([(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(pattern, sentence)])
# [(8, 32), (44, 46)]
```

Comment: Thank you, Zwer. I do need the indexes. However, the above one I accepted also work for indexes. Anyway, I vote your as well.

Comment: I am wondering if you can help me on this as well:  
I need the dash and even the word "and". For the word "and", I want to make sure the pattern does not match it as the start nor the end. Is there a way to do that? Thank you very much. Below are 3 sentences to test:"What is two hundred and four plus one and something?", "What is two hundred and four plus one and and something?", "What is two hundred and four plus and and and something?"